# What is the time to perform review on the changes one made in answers after deletion?

Tags: support, status-completed, post-ban

I wrote some answers which have been deleted. This had led to the situation where my account is answer-banned; I cannot answer any question anymore.

I had changed/edited my answers (deleted ones) and now I am waiting for the review of my changes in the hope that my account will be unblocked from answering.

How long shall I wait? Is there any defined time when someone will perform  review on my changes?

Here are the links:

[why does a set of commands in batch tend to stop after running only some of the commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783144/why-does-a-set-of-commands-in-batch-tend-to-stop-after-running-only-some-of-the/39161153#39161153)

[mvn test fails because of Surefire JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439564/mvn-test-fails-because-of-surefire-jdk-version/38432014#38432014)

[mvn test fails because of Surefire JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439564/mvn-test-fails-because-of-surefire-jdk-version/38438392#38438392)

[Why does only the first line of this Windows batch file execute but all three lines execute in a command shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036754/why-does-only-the-first-line-of-this-windows-batch-file-execute-but-all-three-li/39161582#39161582)

[Execute multiple maven project from MS bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130312/execute-multiple-maven-project-from-ms-bat-file/39161382#39161382)

[How to execute more than one maven command in bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573062/how-to-execute-more-than-one-maven-command-in-bat-file/39161234#39161234)

Comment: Could you link to the answers in question please.

Comment: I did not place them in my question, to avoid situation when my question is very specific to me :-).

Comment: @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki you seemed to answer a lot of questions with just links to other site answers and that's why they were deleted... I see you've made a few changes though... what do you intend to do in future?

Comment: The complete story is a bit more complicated. I was working on some topics and I had searched answers in the net. Then I found that in SO there are soft-duplicates. As I am new user neither I cannot mark duplicates nor add comments, so I summarized those soft-duplicates in one answer and post it :-). I was long time researcher and I think better is to cite someone then copy-paste text. I think here there is misunderstanding of my intention. I am not sure what was the best way to act in the situation I was, but I see my solution was painful for me :-(.

Comment: You are now risking more bans for removing attribution from posts - see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38438392/revisions which completely removed any traces of where you copy-pasted answer from (other edits seem to follow the same pattern - copy part of information from the link and remove the link). You may want to search and read existing Meta posts about link-only answers.

Comment: 1. I did not copy-pasted any answers. 2. What is the good procedure in such a case? 3. Is there any way out from this deadlock? 4. The link does not work for me - page does not exist.

Comment: SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki if you look at history of http://stackoverflow.com/a/38438392/477420 you can clearly see link in version 1 and no link in version 2, but answer is exact copy-paste from the link. On other hand @BradLarson looked at the post and reverted deletion - so you are may be fine  for this particular case (Note that I'd flag that edit as "no attribution given" if I'd see it in review queue, but not when coming from Meta link)

Comment: Hmm... I think I am lost. I am happy with any solution that will give me ability to write answers. So if you undelete my answer and this will unblock my account, thanks a lot! I will try. If the answers remain deleted, but someone can release lock, I am happy too. According to "but answer is exact copy-paste from the link." is MY answer in another similar question. This is the main point here. The original idea of the SO was/is to give the best possible answers on the questions. Is the questions and answers are spread over some places, then I think summary from 4 places is very useful, or?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Did you look at the author of the content behind the links? You don't really need attribution to something you wrote yourself.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks - I did not. I was not expecting them to copy-paste they own answer to multiple posts. Indeed one doesn't need attribution in that case... On other hand one should not be doing so - if copy-paste answer answers the question it should likely be duplicate instead (or answer tailored to the question). Does not look like good approach to get out of answer ban to me. I pay more attention if I ever need to raise flag for "plagiarism".

Comment: @AlexeiLenkov: I have another long mail exchange with SO support where THEY told me to do those changes and to type my answers couple of times. Your wording "plagiarism" is quite negative. Are you accusing me of violating any kind of copyright law?

Comment: I am still blocked. Is setting up the new account the only solution?

Answer (score 4):

The answers are not going to be automatically reviewed by anyone. Since most all of your answers were deleted by a moderator, a moderator will have to manually undelete them. You can flag them for moderator attention if you feel you have adequately addressed the problem(s) that caused a given answer to be deleted such that it merits undeletion.

Since a mod will need to look into each case personally, and such a flag isn't trivial to investigate, it may take some time for the flags to get handled by a moderator. It could be anywhere from a few hours to a number of days. You have no choice at that point but to just wait.